# MySQLのDELETEが実行されません。

Tags: php, mysql

## 概要

掲示板サイトを作成しています。
PDOを用いてPHPからMySQLに接続しているのですが、DELETE文が実行されません。
add.phpファイルでデータベースにINSERTすることはできますが、
delete.phpファイルが正しく動作せず、DELETE文省略しています
下のファイルの
回答よろしくお願いします。

## 環境

PHP5.5
MYSQL 5.5
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Vagrant仮想環境)
Apache2.4

## delete.php

```
<?php
$user = "root";
$pass = "abcd4649";
try{
    if(empty($_GET['thid'])) throw new Exception(error);
    $thid = $_GET['thid'];
    $dbh =new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db1;charset=utf8',$user,$pass);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "DELETE FROM title WHERE thid=?";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(1,$title,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $dbh = null;
    echo "ID:" . htmlspecialchars($thid,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8') . "の削除が完了しました。";
    echo "<a href='index.php'>トップページへ戻る</a>";
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo "エラー発生:" . htmlspecialchars($e->getMEssage(),ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "<Br>";
}
?>
```

## add.php

```
<?php
$user="root";
$pass="abcd4649";
$title=$_POST['title'];
try{
    $dbh =new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db1;charset=utf8',$user,$pass);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO title (title) VALUES(?)";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(1,$title,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $dbh = null;
    echo "スレッドの作成が完了しました。<br>";
    echo"<a href=index.php>トップページへ戻る</a>";
} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "エラー発生:" . htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage(),ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    die();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

delete.phpでは`$title`変数が設定されていないようですが？